# the command y3s to copy three lines in Normal Mode in Vim

Tags: vim, vi

According to Vim's Verb, Noun, and Modifier logic the command `y3s` should potentially copy three sentences, but in my version of Vim it doesn't do that. I am wondering if there is a reason for it. Looking up online it seems like there are other ways to copy a specific number of sentences, but I am curious why this approach doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several misconceptions here. First, there is a difference between *motions* and *text objects*.

A motion (`:help navigation`) is a command that changes the position of the cursor: `l` for right, `j` for down, `)` for sentence forward, `2Fx` backward to before-previous `x` in the same line, `/foo/e+2<CR>` forward to 2 characters after the end of next `foo`, `w` start of next word. Commands whose argument is a motion operate on the text span from the current position to the new motion-specified position. `dw` thus deletes from current position to the start of the next word.

A text object (`:help text-objects`) specifies a semantic unit of text; it typically consists of two keypresses, the first of which is `i` (inside, inner) or `a` (a, an, around). `i"` inside double quotes, `a(` around parenthesis, `is` inner sentence (i.e. without spaces around it), `2aw` twice a word. Thus `daw` delete around this word (including the space), or simpler, delete a word.

The difference is clear: if you are in the middle of a word, e.g. `Some peng|uins fly` (with `|` representing the cursor), `dw` gives you `Some peng|fly` (deleting from cursor to start of the next word), while `daw` gives you `Some |fly` (deleting the entire word `penguins`, along with the next space because of the "around" modifier). `diw` would give you `Some | fly` (not including the space into the deletion).

As you'll note, "sentence" has a different mapping in text motions (`(` sentence backward, `)` sentence forward) and text objects (`is` inner sentence, `as` a sentence). Meanwhile, `(` as a text object, equivalently to `)` and `b`, is everything inside, or around, parentheses; and `s` as a text motion does not exist by default.

Thus, `y2s` is not a known mapping, since you are deleting by *motion* (no `i` or `a`), and there is no motion `s`; it will not do anything.

You can use `y2)`, which would yank about a sentence and a half (i.e. from cursor to the start of the second next sentence); or you can use `y2as` to yank the current sentence and the next sentence and a space after it; or `y2is` for the same except without that last space; but you cannot use `y2s`. (You can also write all of those as `2y)`, `2yas`, `2yis`.)

In `y2y` (or equivalently `2yy`), the second `y` is the duplication of the operator. It is almost a rule in Vim that the motion equal to the operator is a line: `yy` yank a line, `dd` delete a line, `gqgq` (or `gqq`) reformat a line, `==` filter a line, `gugu` (or `guu`) uppercase a line etc. The reason is a simple convenience: lines are what we operate on most frequently, and it's hard to make a faster incantation than the same key pressed twice. Thus, the second `y` by itself does not have a meaning: it signifies that the first `y` is working on lines (thus `y2y` or `2yy` yank two lines).

The whole `:help motion.txt` page is a very useful read, I heartily recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy 3 lines, you should do `y3y`, not `y3s`. `y` stands for Yank or copy.

Update,

@Amadan 's answer has more explanation and also for why `y3y` works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Doesn't `s` also represent a sentence? if for example, I wanted to do copy a sentence, I would do `yis`. Or does the meaning change when there is a number involved? Also, could you please tell me what does the second `y` in `y2y` represent?

Comment: OP is asking about deleting sentences, not lines; and `s` is "substitute" as a command, which is irrelevant when talking about another command (`y`).

Comment: this is wrong, `s` is not substitute in this context, it just does not exist. `y` is the command and it is waiting for a textobject not a second command! `yy` is a shortcut to `y_`.  `_` means line. So `y3y` is the same as `y3_` -> "yank 3 lines" so the text object is `_`. Please read the answer of @Amadan since that is the correct explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Simpley `3Y` will do, where `Y` will yank a line and `3` will repeat it 3 times. In Vim there are no sentences, only lines, words, and characters.